# Matrix using matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

this is my first question on this website.  I'm looking at a Matlab problem, and don't seem to know how to do it.  Before I type the question, I want to make it clear that I'm looking for an UNDERSTANDING, NOT an ANSWER.  Although, I must admit, I won't be angry if an answer is posted.  But more importantly, I need to understand this.

"The matrix factorization LU = PA can be used to compute the determinant of A. We have

`det(L)det(U) = det(P)det(A)`.

Because L is triangular with ones on the diagonal, det(L) = 1. Because U is
triangular, det(U) = u 11 u 22 · · · u nn . Because P is a permutation, det(P) =
+1 if the number of interchanges is even and −1 if it is odd. So
det(A) = ±u 11 u 22 · · · u nn .

Modify the lutx function so that it returns four outputs.

```
function [L,U,p,sig] = lutx(A)
%LU Triangular factorization
% [L,U,p,sig] = lutx(A) computes a unit lower triangular
% matrix L, an upper triangular matrix U, a permutation
% vector p, and a scalar sig, so that L*U = A(p,:) and
% sig = +1 or -1 if p is an even or odd permutation.
```

Write a function mydet(A) that uses your modified lutx to compute the
determinant of A. In Matlab, the product u 11 u 22 · · · u nn can be computed
by the expression prod(diag(U))."`

The lutx code can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4822-%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20using-numerical-computing-with-matlab-in-the-classroom/content/lutx.m):

I'm having difficulty understanding the concept of the problem, and also the code that needs to be written.  Any help would be very appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: looks like a homework to me ;)

Comment: It is.  Am I in the wrong to post it?  It's why I'm asking for pointers versus an answer.

Comment: If you expect someone solve it for you, yes. You need to show what have you tried so far, and people can help you to solve the problems you are dealing with.

Comment: That's understandable.  Unfortunately, this is a difficult class for me, and I wish that I could say that I've tried a lot.  Truth is, I'm struggling with an overall understanding of how a matrix A is decomposed into an upper, lower, and permutation (even though I am perfectly aware of what they are). After typing the lutx code into octave, it produces one matrix, and I don't know what it is!  I expected a lower, upper, and permutation matrix to be in the output.  So that's the first problem, and the only one I have right now, because I don't know how to go further than that.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your problem in the following equation:

```
det(L)det(U) = det(P)det(A)
```

actually the lutx function decompose the input matrix and returns the decomposed elements. It means if you give it the A matrix, it will calculate the L,U,p. you can check the source code.

actually in your problem, three out of four elements are 'known', so you can use the lutx function to find the **det(A)**.
because :

```
det(A) = det(L)det(U) / det(P);
```

so what you can do is this:

```
[L,U,p,sig] = lutx(A); % here I am using the modified version of lutx that you mentioned
DetA = 1 * prod(diag(U)) * sig;
```

because, **det(L) = 1** (I mention it in the previous line of code just for underestanding), and **det(U) = prod(diag(U))**, and **sig** gives the sign.

finally you can compare your result with matlab function: **det(A)**.

Comment: You have no idea how grateful I am to even have a response. Thank you.  Frankly, I feel dumb to ask this, but how come there's only one matrix in the output of that code?  I'm trying to understand why I can't view the U, L, and P, when I type in an arbitrary 3x3 matrix A, and execute lutx(A).

Comment: If you don't tell MATLAB that you want 3 outputs, it will only give you the first one. Try `[L,U,P] = lutx(A);`. I haven't tested that, you might need to remove the square brackets `[]`. BTW, that's not a dumb question, it's not obvious that's what to do unless you've done it before :-)

Comment: Thanks again to darthbith and NKN for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The exercise appears to be mainly to compute "sig", which lutx currently doesn't return. As a hint, you must compute

```
 delta_p = (1:length(p))-p;
```

and check whether delta_p has an even or odd number of non-zero elements. That will determine the sign of sig.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this.  The code is simple, and once I have an understanding, I'll be able to create crafty code to computer the number of non-zero elements, but what is going on here?  I'm not sure how (1:length(p))-p can be computed.

Comment: The expression `(1:length(p))-p` _is_ the way you compute it. Here `p` is the `p` already provided to you by `lutx()`.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to conceptualize it, and I don't see how arithmetic can be done given that they have different dimensions.

Comment: They don't have different dimensions, assuming p is a row vector. If p is a column vector, you would just transpose it, or transpose the vector `1:length(p)`, to make them match.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried.  Just making sure.  Thank you so much.